# Working in the US, paid by a foreign company

Tags: united-states, employment

While studying in the US, I'm going to do some computer based work for a company outside of the US. Will this be considered work in the US?

Comment: Not a lawyer. This is the wrong site to ask. Yes, it counts as work. I wanted to do that myself - ended up going through the whole visa process.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for the comment. You know of the right site?

Comment: Many student visas only allow restricted work (if any at all). You should check at your university's international student office.

Comment: the simple answer is "yes, of course obviously it's work".  (What difference could it possibly make that you also happen to be studying?)  It's extremely likely your visa does NOT permit this.  This would be a question for the expats site.

Comment: I agree that ExPats might be a better place for this question, since it is directly linked to visa status.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this will be considered work in the US. Your income will be taxable by the US as US-sourced income. From immigration law perspective, you need to be in a status that allows employment.